# 'CGAffineTransformMake' is unavailable in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics

This code doesn't compile in swift 3:

```
let flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height)
context.concatenate(flipVertical)
```

How would I convert this over?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `CGAffineTransform`?

Comment: I did not realize it was renamed to not have `make` in its name.

Comment: It wasn't renamed.

Comment: ? The initializer has been renamed.

Comment: No, the old convenience functions were discarded in favor of directly creating an instance of a `CGAffineTransform` using the appropriate initializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3, these free-standing functions have been replaced with the `init` syntax:

```
let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: newSize.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGAffineTransformMake` became `CGAffineTransform` and initializers now require labels for it.

```
let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: newSize.height)
context.concatenate(flipVertical)
```

For more information, check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform) of `CGAffineTransform`.